# SQL using SUM and GROUPED by two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following sample table:

[image]

And I need to write a query that does the following:

```
A. SUMS column D for category 1 and category 2 (note the duplicates; 
I only need one row from each category.

B. GROUP BY column B and column A - The output for each row will look as follows:

Customer 1        (SUM(category 1 and 2 for customer 1(without duplicates))

Customer 2        (SUM(category 1 and 2 for customer 2(without duplicates))

Customer 3        (SUM(category 1 and 2 for customer 3(without duplicates))
```

I am using the following query/sub-query, but I dint know how to group by both columns so the SUM and the related customer will show:

```
SELECT SUM(col_d) AS total_growth FROM (SELECT col_d from table       WHERE 
account_manager_id = '159795'        GROUP BY col_c) as total LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT col_d) 
FROM table 
WHERE category IN ('category 1','category 2') AND account_manager_id = '159795'
GROUP BY customer
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

Comment: thanks for your input and help. My customers have different numbers of categories that need to be in the SUM, is there any way I can I can select all of the different categories for each customer?

Comment: @TechnoCripple : Well, then just remove `category IN ('category 1','category 2')`.

Comment: @TechnoCripple : Have you succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
SELECT A, SUM(D)
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, D
    FROM table
    WHERE C IN ('category 1','category 2')
) TEMP
GROUP BY A, B
```